# Remove Shipping Option if Condition is Met

Tags: php, magento

I would like to remove the standard shipping option `productmatrix_Standard` from the shipping methods if a certain condition is met.  I believe I need to override the following:

```
/**
 * One page checkout status
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Checkout
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
{
    protected $_rates;
    protected $_address;

    public function getShippingRates()
    {

        if (empty($this->_rates)) {
            $this->getAddress()->collectShippingRates()->save();

            $groups = $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
            /*
            if (!empty($groups)) {
                $ratesFilter = new Varien_Filter_Object_Grid();
                $ratesFilter->addFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getPriceFilter(), 'price');

                foreach ($groups as $code => $groupItems) {
                    $groups[$code] = $ratesFilter->filter($groupItems);
                }
            }
            */

            return $this->_rates = $groups;
        }

        return $this->_rates;
    }
}
```

How can I remove existing shipping methods from this collection, or empty it and re-build it manually, skipping the `productmatrix_Standard` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with

```
<?php

    public function getShippingRates() {

        if (empty($this->_rates)) {

            $this->getAddress()->collectShippingRates()->save();

            $groups = $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

            if ($this->someCondition()) {

                $badMethods = array('productmatrix_Standard');

                // Loop through groups (productmatrix)
                // pass by reference for unset later
                foreach ($groups as $code => &$groupItems) {

                    // Lopp through methods (standards, 2day)
                    foreach($groupItems as $key => $item) {

                        // Check for bad shipping methods
                        if (in_array($item->getCode(), $badMethods)) {

                            // Remove the method from the shipping groups
                            unset($groupItems[$key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->_rates = $groups;
        }

        return $this->_rates;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should instead override "`function collectRates()`" in the shipping model.
e.g. inside 
`/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php`
or 
`/app/code/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php`

All of the details about the address and cart are available at the time `collectRates()` is run on each carrier.  This makes it ideal to filter out specific rates, or changing their `names/price.`